# Angular server side typeahead

Tags: angular, typeahead

I tried to implement a typeahead using angular 5 with server side filter. Therefore when something changes in that field I make a request to server for results from db. The problem is that the typeahead doesn't show the results, it only show 2 or 3 when from server comes 10 results (I use maximum take 10).

Here is my html code:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterName"[typeahead]="usersList" (keyup)="getUsers()" typeaheadOptionField="name"/>
```

And here is my typescript code:

```
 getUsers() {
        this._adminService.getUsers(this.filterName).subscribe(
            rsp => { this.usersList = rsp; },
            error => {});
    }
```

The typeahead beahave difrently of what I would expect. For example when you write the letter 't' it only shows the firs 2 results although from server I receive 10. Also when I type another letter the result change but not in the way I expect.

Comment: HTML code: 
<input class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="filterName" type="text" [typeahead]="usersList" typeaheadOptionField="name" (keyup)="getUsers()" />